# How to select a value of a DropDownList that has been returned from a database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, list, object, combobox

I have a web update form where every control is a property of the same table. It should work this way:
Whenever I select a value from the main(the first) dropdownlist, a query should be run getting all of the fields(properties) and filling the other controls depending of the value I selected.

Event Code:

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim objModel As New ModelDAO ' the data access class taht contains search method          
        Dim myobject = objModel.searchObject(DropDownList1.Text)                      
        TextBox1.Text = myobject.Property2
        DropDownList2.SelectedValue = myobject.Property3 'what's wrong here?
    End Sub
```

Controls:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="MODEL" DataValueField="MODEL"
                    AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="-Select-" Value="" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>EDS</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BDS</asp:ListItem>                            
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

It works except the second DropDownList, I don't know how to change the selected value, I tried this:

```
DropDownList2.Text = myobject.Property3
```

and this:

```
DropDownList2.SelectedValue = myobject.Property3
```

But in both cases dropdownlist2 shows no selected item.

NOTE: Since textbox.text does get the right value I don't think search method has any problem, that's why I'm not posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work that way unfortunately.  I'll give you pseudocode since I'm a C#er, but this is how I normally do it:

```
Dim int i = 0
ForEach Item in DDL.Items
    If Item.Text = databaseResult
        DDL.SelectedIndex = i
        ExitLoop
    EndIf
    i = i + 1
EndForEach
```

Here is the working code from the comment thread below:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0 
For Each listitem In DropDownList1.Items 
    If DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text = myobject.property Then 
        DropDownList3.SelectedIndex = i 
        Exit For 
    End If 
    i = i + 1 
Next
```

Comment: Why does it not work that way? Setting the `SelectedValue` is the same as looping the items and setting the `Selected` property of the first matching item to `True` after `ClearSelection` was called.

Comment: In my experience I've never had SelectedValue work.  It's just never worked for me.

Comment: Thanks I converted into VB and it worked: Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each listitem In DropDownList1.Items
            If DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text = myobject.property Then
                DropDownList3.SelectedIndex = i
                Exit For
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Next

Answer (score 1):

If VB is anything like C# (where I've had similar problems), then try

```
DropDownList2.SelectedItem = myobject.Property3
```

Make sure the item you want selected is in the controls list of items otherwise it still won't work.

Comment: [`DropDownList.SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `ListItem` not a custom object.

Comment: Error: Property 'SelectedItem' is 'ReadOnly'

Comment: Well that would answer the statement of VB being like C# in this case... C# doesn't have DropDownList as its own control so it requires the use of a ComboBox with the drop-down style set to drop-down. In this case, SelectedItem is the only way to things to work for me. Thanks for the points though. :)

Comment: @phalanx I don't know if this will help but a read of SelectedValue from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.100).aspx suggests that SelectedValue is chosen from the value and not the text. If you said DropDownList2.SelectedValue = "0", the text would display "-Select-". Maybe add values to the EDS and BDS list items. From the aformentioned page... "The SelectedValue property can also be used to select an item in the list control by setting it with the **value** of the item."

Comment: Interesting, I'm gonna try it, until now I've never Know how to use selectedvalue in a properly way.

Answer (score 1):

Here try this:

```
        int i = 0;
        foreach (ListItem item in YourDropDownList.Items)
        {
            //Check it see if your item actually exists in the list
            //Could also be item.Text                
            if (item.Value.ToLower() == value)
            {
                item.Selected = true;
                YourDropDownList.SelectedIndex = i;
                break;
            }
            else
                item.Selected = false;

            i++;
        }

        if (YourDropDownList.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {                
            YourDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(YourDropDownList, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
```

Not sure if this will work, you can try it:

```
    YourDropDownList.SelectedValue = myobject.Property3
    YourDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(YourDropDownList, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: iSelectedIndex doesn't provide any benefit here if you just exit the loop once you've matched item.Value.  This is a tad bloated.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely I needed to use iSelectedIndex in order to figure out what the index was with the matching ListItem and store it.

Comment: Why can't you just use i?

Comment: Because I don't break out of the Foreach when I find the matching ListItem, thus i is incremented to the end. I could probably optimize this with a break. :)

Comment: Isn't it inefficient to continue looping through items after you've found your match?

Comment: item.Selected is redundant, and I'm not sure why you're calling YourDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged() at the end.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely I was calling that function so that the event handler executes. I have found that if you just use .Selected or .SelectedIndex than the event handler will not execute. I thought that he might want to do this since he is selecting a drop down list value in code.

Answer (score 1):

So you have this working apart from the showing of the selectedValue in the second dropdown?

Remember when making comparsions it has to be equal to the parent value (usualy an integer)

another course of concerns is postback issues!

Answer (score 0):

Its as simple as this...

```
ddlstate.SelectedIndex = ddlstate.Items.IndexOf(ddlstate.Items.FindByValue(dt.Rows[0]["state"].ToString()));
```

**`state`** is column name in database.

**`ddlstate`** is your dropdownlist id.