# How to show item in dropdownlist as being selected when we have corresponding datatextfield from gridview selected row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatextfield

**Code**:

```
DataSet ds = _dalEquipmentwiseCheckList.getEquipmentName();

ddEquipmentName.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

ddEquipmentName.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns[1].ToString();
ddEquipmentName.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ToString();
ddEquipmentName.DataBind();
```

**What I want is: when selecting a row in the GridView, the corresponding equipment name
should get selected in the dropdown list:**

var selectRow = MyGridView.SelectedRow;

```
ddEquipmentName.SelectedValue = selectRow.Cells[2].Text;
****//this is giving me error****
```

Comment: This will help you--easily translated to C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981920/how-to-select-a-value-of-a-dropdownlist-that-has-been-returned-from-a-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selected value does not work in this way. Try this:

```
ddEquipmentName.SelectedIndex = ddEquipmentName.Items.IndexOf(ddEquipmentName.Items.FindByText(selectRow.Cells[2].Text));
```

Comment: your code work as i used FindByText in place of FindByValue
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
GridViewRow selectRow = MyGridView.SelectedRow;    
ddEquipmentName.selectedItem.Text = selectRow.Cells[2].Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 void setDataContext()
{
    var selectRow = GridEquipmentChechList.MyGridView.SelectedRow;
    if (selectRow != null)
    {
        txtECNumber.Text = selectRow.Cells[1].Text;
        **ddEquipmentName.SelectedIndex = ddEquipmentName.Items.IndexOf(ddEquipmentName.Items.FindByText(selectRow.Cells[2].Text));**
        **ddDescription.SelectedIndex = ddDescription.Items.IndexOf(ddDescription.Items.FindByText(selectRow.Cells[3].Text));**
    }
}
```